# How to write Python script read text and write in XML format

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need a Python script to read the below text from text file:

```
"Re-integratieassistent – modelnummer rea 202"
```

and write it into an XML file.

The issue when writing in XML is using UTF-8 encoding as it writes as:

```
"Re-integratieassistent  modelnummer rea 202"
```

`"-"` is missing between `"integratieassistent"` and `"modelnumber"`

How do I solve this?

My current code:

```
with codecs.open(file,encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore', mode="r") as curr_file:
    for line in curr_file.readlines():

        # Increment the counter because we encountered the XML start or begin elements
        #line = line.encode('utf-8')

        if line.find("<soapenv:Envelope") != -1 or line.find("</soapenv:Envelope") != -1 :
            i=i+1
        if (i == 1):
            file_i = codecs.open(inputFolder_new+"/"+filename,encoding='utf-8', mode="a")
            file_i.writelines(line)
        if (i == 3):
            file_o = codecs.open(outputFolder_new+"/"+filename, encoding='utf-8', mode="a")
            file_o.writelines(line)
        if (i == 4):
            file_i.writelines("</soapenv:Envelope>")
            file_o.writelines("</soapenv:Envelope>")
```

Comment: Please fix your version tags - you're either using Python 2 or Python 3.

Comment: Is your input file actually encoded in utf8? What's the contents of `line` when you are trying to writting to the file?

Comment: Hi thanks.My input file is as below format 
                                          <suppModulePolicyConditionDesc>Re-integratieassistent – modelnummer rea 202</suppModulePolicyConditionDesc>
                                      </SuppModulePolicyConditionsOutput>         
       
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> which is in text file

Comment: Also it is  under <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           
       
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Yes input file is encoded in utf8

Answer (score 0):

Python's interfaces for processing XML are grouped in the `xml` [package](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file).

You might want to consider `xml.etree.ElementTree` for modifying an xml file.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse(file)
```

Then use `root.findall('{namespace}nodename')`. or `root.find()`. You can loop through each node trying to find your item of interest.

Add a subelement with `ET.SubElement(an_element_object, 'your element')`.

It's hard to be more precise without knowing what your XML file looks like.

Comment: My XML file contains both Request and Response its big to post here

Comment: Well, let me know if you have any questions on the above, then